# "is depended upon by" - how should I understand it?

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english

I'd like to ask you about some phrase that I bumped into, and it is:
*is depended upon by*

So, when someone says *A is depended upon by B*, what exactly does it mean?

1. that A affects B (where A is independent)
2. that B affects A (where B is independent)

I'm asking purely from linguistic perspective (the phrase can be seen in a tool for software development, and it causes misunderstandings, so I'm wondering if it's me who just understands it wrong).

Comment: **"A is depended upon by B"** means (B needs A or B depends upon A). So I would say that this is **1. that A affects B (where A is independent)** and **2. that B affects A (where B is independent)** is for **"B is depended upon by A" (A needs B)**

Answer (score 1):

It is B that depends on A. In this relationship A affects B and A is independent.